# In the click event Jquery how is $(this)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, this

I have `click` event with jquery and i want to know how is selector clicked...

```
$('#parent').on('click','#child',function(){
 //....
});  


<div id="parent">
 <div id="child">
 </div>
</div>
```

**$(this)** is `#parent` or `#child` ?

Comment: Couldn't you just test this out yourself if you didn't find the relevant documentation? just put console.log(this); in your event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context `this` is related to the event target.  In your case is `#child`.

Further, you don't need event delegation when the `id` is available, so bind that event as follow:

```
$('#child').on('click',function(){
 //....
});
```

Comment: in my case #child is added to doom after some functions ;)

Answer (score 4):

It's the child, why did you not just try

```
$('#parent').on('click','#child',function(){
    console.log($(this));
});
```

```js
$('#parent').on('click','#child',function(){
    console.log($(this));
});
```

```css
#child {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is called `Event delegation` which allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

So, `$(this)` here is always referring to the clicked child element to a parent element, which here is `#child`.

A simple dynamically added element demo:

```js
// Attach Event
// on(events, selector, handler);
$('#container').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('Anchor clicked!');
  alert('Anchor clicked!');
});

// Create elements dynamically
$('#container').append('<a href="#output">Click me!</a>');
```

```css
body{font:12px Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#333;margin:20px}
h1{font-size:1.4em;margin-bottom:20px}
h2{font-size:1.2em}
#container{border:1px dashed #aaa;font-size:1em;padding:10px}
a{color:green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Dynamically added link:</h2>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just write something like this to check.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#parent').on('click','#child',function(){
    console.log("This:", $(this));
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
 Parent
 <div id="child">
   CHILD (click on it)
 </div>
</div>
```